# Start Spark Thrift Server in Windows 10

Tags: apache-spark, spark-thriftserver

I'm trying to start Spark Thrift Server using

D:\spark\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2 spark-internal

in cmd.

However, after I reach the below line, cmd hangs forever. Does anyone know the reason? Thanks for any advice.

INFO  ThriftCLIService:98 - Starting ThriftBinaryCLIService on port 10000 with 5...500 worker threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple - server is started and waits for the connections on port 10000. Try `beeline` or other JDBC client and connect to `jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000` (in different terminal window/tab).

Comment: Thanks. I recently realized that I need another cmd window in Windows. In Mac, one command prompt is fine.